# How to find a room in Lille under these conditions?

Tags: france, students, europe, accommodation

I am a student who will move to Lille, France from a 3rd world country.

I have checked the websites mentioned by the university, websites mentioned by the Campus France, websites on the guide given to me by the Campus France officer but failed to find a room.

The reasons might be following: Due to depression and anxiety (reason is career setbacks), I want to live in a studio (room with kitchen, toilet, shower only for me). The monthly I can spend is 340 euros on a room. My scholarship doesn't allow me to spend more. I am fine with travelling for classes by cycle or train or bus but room must be a studio. I want to live in some suburb that will allow me to live with my limited means.

Can you please tell me resources and tips on how should I try finding a room in suburbs of Lille while living in my own country?

Till I don't show proof where I will live in Lille, I can't even apply for visa and my classes are from 29 August.

Can you please guide?

Comment: I am not familiar with current options for student housing and Lille is not the worse area of the country but it could be that your budget is just not sufficient. It certainly wouldn't be on the private market in cities like Paris, Bordeaux or Lyon.

Comment: I would also add that what you describe is not a room, it's usually called a “studio“ (also in French). By contrast, traditional student housing mostly consisted of individual rooms with shared bathrooms and kitchens. I think you can now find newer ones with en-suite bathrooms but a shared kitchen. This type of accommodation might barely fit within your budget but there are waiting lists and they are not always very quiet. That's why it's important to be specific about what you are looking for.

Comment: @Relaxed I know it is called a studio. due to budget constraint's I want to live in Suburbs.

Comment: Why call it a room, then? This lead me to believe you were looking for the wrong kind of accommodation. Looking outside the city center makes sense but I am not sure it will be enough to find one at your price point.

Comment: As an example, here is a [search on seloger.com](https://www.seloger.com/list.htm?projects=1&types=1&isochronepoints=[{%22sources%22:[{%22id%22:%220%22,%22lat%22:50.7245925,%22lng%22:3.1637905,%22tm%22:{%22transit%22:{}},%22address%22:%22Rue%20Sainte-Barbe,%2059200%20Tourcoing,%20France%22}],%22polygonConfiguration%22:{%22values%22:[2700],%22intersectionMode%22:%22Intersection%22,%22placeType%22:3}}]&price=NaN/380&mandatorycommodities=0&enterprise=0&qsVersion=1.0&m=homepage_advanced_search-redirection-search_results) based on distance from one of the campuses of Lille university.

Comment: Have you considered to book a hotel/hostel/Airbnb and use that as initial place for your visa application and to search for something more permanent once you arrive?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy No, I am thinking a room to book from here only to save money. Btw,  I have thought about it and once I am not able to book the room from here I will certainly do airbnb booking.

Comment: You must take into account that it is very difficult to rent a studio in the private market in France if you are not present, and prone to scams. You shouldn't send money to someone for a studio that you have not visited.

Comment: @audionuma Thanks for telling me! I will not pay money from my country.

Comment: Does your rental budget allow for essential/mandatory extras, such as internet services, local taxes etc? I’m not familiar with the system in France but typically the existence of a university nearby drives up demand and therefore prices, plus there can be extras in the rental small print, like a couple of months’ rental up front as a deposit

Comment: @Traveller No, I don't need wifi or other services. I don't want to life very near to university as my budget will not allow it. So, that is the reason I am looking for room in suburbs.

Comment: Extra fees may be unavoidable eg insurance, seevices like electricity/gas, possibly property tax https://www.expatica.com/fr/housing/renting/rent-in-france-101131/ You may need wifi for studying of course

Comment: You have only eight days before classes begin. Before classes begin, you must a) find a place to live or create an accommodation plan that will be acceptable to the consular authorities in the French Embassy in India; and b) apply for a French visa; and (c) have that visa issued; and d) buy a plane ticket; and d) travel to Lille; and e) accomplish whatever administrative/enrollment are presented by the school. It is very unlikely these tasks be finished in eight days. It would be prudent to consider asking the school if your enrollment can be postponed for a semester or a year.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Due to the conditions I am in , this is not a possibility.

Comment: @Relaxed the website you mentioned was a bit useful,can you mention more websites or guidence?

Comment: @user Not much, do you know https://www.messervices.etudiant.gouv.fr/envole/ and https://trouverunlogement.lescrous.fr/